# В чем принципиальный выигрыш при использовании MVVM вместо MVC

Tags: swift, mvc, mvvm

сейчас изучаю Swift и застопорился на изучении архитектур.
Для начала я начал изучать архитектуру MVC, сразу все делаю без сторибордов чисто в коде, с изучение проблем не возникло, все более или менее понятно:
View - это некое UIView(), в котором у нас создаются UI элементы и настраиваются constraints, имеет несколько функций, которые вызываются из контроллера, для изменения тех или иных элементов, действия пользователя передает в контроллер для обработки и изменений интерфейса. Как и на многих картинках, это легко представить, выглядит примерно вот так:

[image: MVC example]

MVC славится как Massive View Controller потому что в ViewController очень много кода, и у него много ответственности, поэтому MVVM в этом плане лучше.

Что мы имеем при MVVM: Наш контроллер больше не выводит настройку констрейнтов в View, а настраивает их внутри себя, а так же содержит в себе ViewModel, которая может дать контроллеру все необходимые данные, а сам контроллер (он же View) передает события во вьюМодель, которая проводит некую логику, и передает все обратно.

[image: MVVM example]

И самое главное, ведь получается все то, что было в контроллере или "нагружало" его, мы вынесли в ViewModel, соответственно загрузив теперь его тем же самым кодом, мы нагрузили теперь его, а в контроллер мы просто передали ту кучу кода по настройке лайяута, которая была во view при MVC

На мой взгляд это просто смена шила на мыло, и не решает проблему неразделенной ответственности, так в чем же MVVM лучше MVC и почему никто не говорит что MVVM - View and Massive ViewModel? :)

Comment: Почитайте https://habr.com/ru/company/badoo/blog/281162/

Comment: Дополняю: https://medium.com/you-gotta-get-schwifty/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-mvc-mvp-%D0%B8-mvvm-389841cefa70